# Launch app from webview, if it is not installed, redirect to play store

Tags: javascript, android, webview

I have an application which makes some references to some other application using a webview. The behavior that I need is:

-If I have this application installed, it should launch it

-If I don't have this application installed, it should launch the Play Store in the application page.

The application list must be updatable using the html, I mean, the html page will have the applications name and packages, and can not be necessary any app update each time some application changes.

I can use JavaScript in this page, or use any android resource, since it follows the requirements(and does not interferes in the user experience).

Is there a way of doing that?

Comment: First things first. It's possible to launch specific apps with implicit intent-filters and custom url-schemes(defined in the manifest). But the question is: do you own the apps you want to launch? or can you ask for new features?

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at [AppLinks](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/applinks/android) by Facebook, it's a great library that does what you need, or the open source [AppLinks](http://applinks.org/documentation/#navigatingonandroid).

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer.

Do you know if there is a way of doing that, only changing the HTML/JavaScript side?